# How to find the longest string in a column with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the most efficient way in Ruby to find the *longest* string from a column `X`?

Update:

This also sort of works:

```
def self.length_of_longest_number
  Invoice.order("LENGTH(number) DESC").first.number.length
end
```

Just curious to know if's efficient or not. And if it works in MySQL *and* Postgres...

Comment: By 'column' do you mean an ActiveRecord attribute? And by "string with most digits" these are then string representations of integers?

Comment: Yes, I mean an ActiveRecord attribute here. No digits or integers involved here. I made that more clear in my original post now.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to supply sample input and the expected output. You also need to show us you've made an attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: OK, good point actually. I posted an answer myself at the bottom. Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With MySql:

```
# Change your model name and field to your needs
Participant.order("MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(first_name)) desc").limit(1)

# works too:
Participant.order("MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(first_name)) desc").first

# and this is the most efficient to get the field directly:
Participant.limit(1).order("MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(first_name)) desc").pluck(:first_name)
```

With postgres:

```
Participants.limit(1).order("MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(name)) desc").group("id").pluck(:name)
```

Comment: Does that work with mysql and postgresql?

Comment: In mysql it works, should work also in postgres i think.. But i didnt test it.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. I guess it's faster than my attempt?

Comment: Yes, because you are querying all entries from the database and then get the first of them with ruby. Sorting and limiting via SQL is much faster.

Comment: Added another way, but results in the same sql query.

Comment: Would be nice if you answer my answer as correct if it helped you :) thanks

Comment: For me in Postgres it doesn't work with the error
`PG::Error: ERROR:  column "participants.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`, but with
`Participants.limit(1).order("MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(name)) desc").group("id").pluck(:name)` it works

Comment: In Postres this works best for me: `Files::FileChunk.maximum("CHAR_LENGTH(encrypted_data)")`. The request then looks like `SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(encrypted_data)) FROM "file_chunks"`

Answer (score 8):

This also sort of works:

```
def self.length_of_longest_number
  Invoice.order("LENGTH(number) DESC").first.number.length
end
```

Just curious to know if's efficient or not. And if it works in MySQL *and* Postgres...

Comment: Suggest you add this to your question, rather than post it as an answer.